# How do i Swap Data of an Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, swap, jcreator

```
   public class Swap_Numbers {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


              int numTens[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // First array of numbers
              int numHundred[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}; //Second Array of Numbers


       System.out.println (numTens[3]); // I want my numTens displays numHundred
       System.out.println (numHundred[4]); // I want my numHundred displays numTens
  }
 }
```

I just don't know what codes should i use to swap the data of numTens and         numHundred without using extra variables.. hope some can explain me how Thanks!

Comment: The above code does not work!

Comment: Basic....
`temp=b;
b=a;
a=temp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just don't know what codes should i use to swap the data of numTens and numHundred without using extra variables

You shouldn't, basically. Just take the *simple* route of a temporary variable:

```
int[] tmp = numTens;
numTens = numHundred;
numHundred = tmp;
```

For ints you *can* actually swap the values within the arrays using arithmetic without temporary variables (which is *not* the same as swapping which arrays the variables refer to), but it would be very odd to actually find yourself in a situation where you want to do that. Sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] y = { 15, 60, 23, 10, 100 };

        swapValues(x, y);
        System.out.println("x: " + Arrays.toString(x));
        System.out.println("y: " + Arrays.toString(y));
    }

    static void swapValues(int[] a, int[] b) {
        // TODO: Validation
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] += b[i];
            b[i] = a[i] - b[i];
            a[i] -= b[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Even there, I would *actually* write `swapValues` using a temporary variable instead, but the above code is just to prove a point...

Comment: What does java.util.Arrays: does? and what is the function of Arrays.toString?

Comment: @Joey: Did you read the documentation? Which bit of it was unclear to you?

Comment: which documentation sir?

Comment: is it possible to swap datas of String and Int .. like x will be 

String [] x = {Dog, Cat, Mouse, Bird, Rabbit}; and
int[] y = { 15, 60, 23, 10, 100 };

Comment: @Joey: The documentation for `java.util.Arrays.toString`. And no, you can't swap the contents of a `String[]` and an `int[]` - an `int[]` can't hold a string reference, and a `String[]` can't hold an `int`...

Answer (score 2):

For that I'm assuming both arrays are of same size. Then you can do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTens.length; i++)
{
    numTens[i] = numTens[i] + numHundred[i];      // statement 1
    numHundred[i] = numTens[i] - numHundred[i];   // statement 2
    numTens[i] = numTens[i] - numHundred[i];      // statement 3
}
```

Lets take the 2nd elements of both array

```
Ten[2] = 3;
Hundred[2] = 300;
-------------------------------------
Ten[2] = 303    // after statement 1
Hundred[2] = 3  // after statement 2
Ten[2] = 300    // after statement 3
-------------------------------------
Ten[2] = 300;
Hundred[2] = 3;
```

Values are swapped without using temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap the numbers in the array you can do something like this:

```
 void swap(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
 {
      //if parameters are as bellow 
      //arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      //arr2 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};


      if(arr1.length == arr2.length)
      {
           for(int i =0; i < arr1.length ; i++)
           {
                arr1[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
                arr2[i] = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
                arr1[i] = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
           }
      }
      else
      {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int numTens[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // First array of numbers
 int numHundred[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}; //Second Array of Numbers

 for (int i = 0; i < numTens.length; i++) {
      numHundred[i] = numTens[i];
      numTens[i] = numTens[i]*100;
 }

 System.out.println (numTens[3]); 
 System.out.println (numHundred[4]);
```